# Change Cloudera quickstart domain name

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have installed Cloudera Quick start VM in a local server and acessing it from my local machine. The domain name it is using is `quickstart.cloudera` . So for remote access I need to change it every time manually to my local IP address. Where can I edit this setting and give my IP there ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by editing `/etc/hosts`, `dns`, `/etc/sysconfig/network`, `hostname`

for more info [Change hostname](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cm_ag_change_hostnames.html)

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/network is not editable. Can anybody tell which service I need to stop (if any)